# Insert new row in a different sheet and paste value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code for inserting a new row in sheet "Sheet3" in which the first column value is a value I have stored as a Range.

I have made a formula for identifying value in the active sheet, as follows>

```
Dim cellTaxa As Range
Set cellTaxa = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2)
End Sub
```

Basically, the above mentioned formula stores a value in a cell that is one cell down and two cells left from the button that I clicked.

The next thing i want to do is to insert a new row in Sheet 3 in which the first column value is cellTaxa.

I couldn't find anything that will work on my structure.
Any help or hint is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Use [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/11/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) to find the value

Comment: Also storing a value as a range is rarely a good idea

Comment: The .Find may be useful in other purposes, but in my case I don't think it is. In the first sheet I have a column where the values are stored. Next to each of the values, I have a button with the above mentioned code. When I click the button next to a value, my intention is to add that specific value to a different sheet - Sheet3. That sheet will contain only the values where I ran the macro. I hope you have understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub yoursub()

    Dim cellTaxa As Range
    Set cellTaxa = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3") 'replace with your range
    'Would be even better to not use range for a single cell
    ' E.g.: Set cellTaxa = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,7) OR Cells(3,"G")
    'same format can be applied for the .pastespecial part

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert 'adds empty row at "A1"
    cellTaxa.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 'pastes CellTaxa into the newly created row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I don't see the code for inserting the value stored in "cellTaxa" to in the row that was created in Sheet3

Comment: @MarianV. oh sorry about that seems i misunderstood your question. I thought you were looking to find the corresponding value of cellTaxa on a different sheet and add a row after. I'll edit my answer to actually answer your question

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was hoping for! For future usage, what is the alternative to Range and why it is not recommended to be used for a single cell?

Comment: @marian V. You can use the .Cells function, I'll put in the answer with for your consideration. In your particular case it won't have any negative effect, however it is redundant since you range is just a single cell. The major differences is that .cells is a range property while .range is an object